# How mysql repository works in Pentaho User console?

Tags: pentaho, jackrabbit, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

Based on Pentaho guideline (https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Setup/Installation/Archive/MySQL_Repository) I successfully converted pentaho File based repository to MySQL database repository.

Now does anyone have any idea how MySQL repository store the data in database? It means If create new folder, new dashboard or new connection then how pentaho store this data in mysql database. Also need to know which tables is used for which purpose of data store.

Default created attached schema and tables based on mysql pentaho repository. [image]

Please Provide any inputs or any reference material for same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pentaho's repository comprises three third party technologies: Jackrabbit, Hibernate, and Quartz. Reports/Jobs/Transformations and any other artifacts stored inside the Pentaho Server are generally stored in Jackrabbit. Scheduling info and triggers are stored in Quartz. And diagnostic info is stored in Hibernate (such as who accessed what reports, how long a report took to run, etc.).

None of this info is designed to be human readable directly out of the database tables. These are sort of "black box" technologies. These are third party technologies that Pentaho simply leverages for its repository functions. If you have additional questions, I'd recommend checking out the technologies themselves on their project pages.